# How can i disable the swipe for the tab view in certain indexes before i swipe in swift UI?

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-list, swiftui-tabview

```
TabView(index){
   UIView
} 
.gesture(
DragGesture()
    .onChanged {
          if $0.startLocation.x > $0.location.x {
            //left
            // methodTochangeIndex()
                } 
            })
```

Then i updated index on .onchange so that tabview show the certain index tab, but it shows the  animation that moves to same index again. how do i disable that and i cant use the
.disable (true) because it disables the whole ui interaction of tab view row items.

Comment: use ```.deleteDisabled```

Comment: tried but its not helping in this case

Comment: @abinbabu How were you able to overcome this ? any clues?